# How do I download a keyboard on a phone without a keyboard at all

Tags: factory-reset, keyboard

I lost my keyboard after factory reset on my jiayu G4 android phone. I have done everything possible but to no avail.I have used Bluetooth and USB to install apk but it's not installing. I can't log in to my account to access play store. Please is there any other way to get a keyboard. Thanks

Comment: Which keyboard apk did you download? What error are you receiving while installing? [Try the Google Keyboard from this XDA thread.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2312179)

Comment: Jiayu G4 is USB-OTG capeble, so you can attach an USB keyboard to it (with an USB-OTG cable) and you can log in to your account and search a keyboard application on Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

Use an otg-cable and use an USB keyboard

Comment: Great ideas. Finally installed the keyboard. Thanks